# Why memcpy() is able to convert values between Numbering Systems

Tags: c++, memcpy

Please take a look at this snippet of code:

```
uint16_t buffer_array[2]; //Two uint16_t = 4 bytes

temp = swSerial.read(); // Populate with serial readings coming from the sensor 
switch(received_counter)
{
  case 3: //when we receive the fourth byte from the sensor
     buffer_array[0] = temp;
     break;
  case 4: //fifth byte
     buffer_array[0] += temp;
     break;
  case 5: //sixth byte
     buffer_array[1] = temp;
     break;
  case 6: //seventh byte
     buffer_array[1] += temp;
     break;
  default:
     break;
}
```

This code populates the array I declared with readings from a source. When this ends, the array `buffer_array[2]` will have its 4 bytes populated (or 8 hexadecimal values). This is straightforward.

But now we have four raw bytes stored in the array. These four bytes represent a floating point value (i know that from documentation). So we want these 4 bytes (8 hex values) converter to a floating point value.

I can do this with:

```
float voltage;
memcpy(&voltage, &buffer_array, sizeof(float));
```

My question is why does this work? `memcpy()` copies n characters from memory area src to memory area dest.
Does this imply an implicit casting when the values in the memory area is not the same as the value in the destination variable? Am i missing something?

Comment: `memcpy` just copies data, it doesn't convert anything. If the bits you are copying came from a float and you're copying them back into a float you'll get the expected result. If the bits came from an int and you copied them to a float you'd get whatever that bit pattern is when interpreted as a float.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this imply an implicit casting when the values in the memory area is not the same as the value in the destination variable?

No, [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) doesn't even *know* the source and destination types. It just takes two void pointers.

Afterwards, the destination contains the same bit pattern as the source - that's all.

Types are only how we *interpret* a bit pattern. Presumably your serial device has contrived to encode a valid IEEE 754 single-precision [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) in the protocol it sends you.

This use of `memcpy` is the easiest correct way to convert between the type convenient for deserializing the bit pattern, and the type convenient for interpreting it. The bit pattern itself is unchanged.

If you just hexdump (or otherwise inspect in your debugger) the contents of `buffer_array` and `voltage`, you can verify this.

Note that there are older popular approaches, but they rely on [type-punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) and have problems:

1. `union { uint16_t x[2]; float y; };`

   prohibited by strict aliasing (ie, allowing this to work would inhibit loads of other optimizations) and union subobject lifetime rules
2. `float *f = reinterpret_cast<float *>(buffer_array);`

   problems with both strict aliasing *and* possibly alignment, if `alignof(uint16_t[2]) < alignof(float)`

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy()` works *strictly* with bytes, it has no clue what they represent, or what is or isn't valid in the context of the destination. You point it at some memory, you point it at a destination, and you tell it how many bytes to copy. It does that as quickly as it can.

If you want to convert an arbitrary chunk of memory into a floating point value you can just *recast* it as such, at least if you're confident the result is valid.<sup>1</sup> This is as easy as:

```c
float x = *((float*) &buffer_array[0]);
```

Where `buffer_array` is a pointer to your assembled data.

By the way, I'm not sure the floating point value you're constructing is [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) as the format is not split evenly into two 16-bit chunks. What you have there looks like some kind of *fixed point* representation.

--

<sup>1</sup> Don't forget to account for any [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues for both the source data, and your system's architecture.

Comment: Note that if `buffer_array` is not a `char` array, this gives undefined behavior due to aliasing -- the compiler is allowed to assume memory of differing types (not invloving unions or `char`) does not alias, so might not get the latest version of the bits in `buffer_array` if it later changes and you dereference `x` again.

Comment: @ChrisDodd True. Added a dereference to capture the initial value, whatever it is.